# Are MobileFirst client-side APIs such as WL.App.sendActionToNative available when creating a "Cordova" style of application in MobileFirst 7.1?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I'm working with a client who's considering migrating their existing MobileFirst Platform 7.1 [hybrid app](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/hello-world/your-first-hybrid-application/) to [the Cordova app type](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/hello-world/integrating-mfpf-sdk-in-cordova-applications/).

They are trying to understand if this app type would still give them access to MobileFirst APIs such as [WL.App.sendActionToNative](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_action_sender.html?lang=en) to easily bridge the native and JS layers. [The list of supported and unsupported features](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/hello-world/integrating-mfpf-sdk-in-cordova-applications/#supportedMFPFeatures) doesn't mention those APIs; are they supported in Cordova-type apps?

Comment: can you  check this link https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/08/14/ibm-mobilefirst-platform-foundation-7-1-is-here/

Comment: Hi - thanks, I've seen that. I don't think it answers the question directly.

Comment: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/hello-world/integrating-mfpf-sdk-in-cordova-applications/#supportedMFPFeatures

Comment: Nazmul, thanks. That link is in my question :) It doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well...

In a Hybrid app one of the benefits of Worklight was that "we" own the native and web portion. You could create a Cordova plug-in (based on the tutorials) if you wanted, but with SendActionToNative - because we own both sides - helped here by "bridging" the two ends, "negating" the need for a Cordova plug-in. This feature is a "Cordova plug-in" in itself(!) internally.

In a "pure" Cordova apps we don't own both ends. Only the web end... The MFP SDK is now a Cordova plug-in.

Anyway, yes, you could enter the platform folder where the native code is and use those APIs and it should work, but in a Cordova world that does not make much sense - you're not supposed to touch any native code... you're supposed to use Cordova plug-ins in order to interactive with the native later...